# How to store months from NETcdf time dimension (0 corresponding to jan)?

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I have a 3d NETcdf dataset and am trying to work with the precipitation variable. I would like to plot the monthly averages of it over 60 years, but am having difficulty producing a plot that is consistent with previous averaging calculations I did not involving for loops. Here is how I store the values for the january, february and take the mean:

```
janNES = np.empty_like(conprecip[0:720,6:-11,95:141])

for i in range(0,720,12):
     janNES[i]=(NESprecip[i,6:-11,95:141])          

mjanNES=(np.mean(janNES, axis=0))

febNES = np.empty_like(conprecip[0:720,6:-11,95:141])

for i in range(1,720,12):
     febNES[i]=(NESprecip[i,6:-11,95:141]) 

mfebNES=(np.mean(febNES, axis=0))

#values that are plotted, monthly 60 year averages
np.mean(mjanNES-mjan)
np.mean(mfebNES-mfeb)
```

Where 0-11 is jan to dec, so I store values from the other months similarly. I believe there is something wrong with the way I am storing the data as its producing weird results after I subtract the control(mjan and mfeb, store using this method) and take the mean again. Thank you for reading and helping.

Comment: upvote for Bart for useful answer, and at the risk of causing his wrath (he doesn't like alternative language answers ;-) ), also to mention that you could get the monthly mean from the command line with cdo monmean in.nc out.nc, the mean of all Jan, Febs etc with cdo ymonmean in.nc out.nc monthly anomalies around the climate with cdo sub -monmean in.nc -ymonmean in.nc monanom.nc

Comment: @AdrianTompkins, I'm starting to reconsider my *"religious"* beliefs, after posting `xarray` focussed answers/comments on `NetCDF4` questions ;-)

Comment: well, as I mentioned before, I understand your point perfectly, but for me stackexchange is a source for all, so many readers may be looking for an answer to the question posed, but may not be wedded to the OP's language of choice, and sometimes even the posters themselves don't realize these other options exist.  One OP wrote a comment saying that they had converted to using CDO/NCO for all such netcdf manipulation tasks, even though they had posted a question seeking an answer in R... But anyway, your answer is more appropriate. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the first dimension of your `janNES` array is 720, but when you loop over time with:

```
for i in range(0,720,12):
    janNES[i]=...
```

You are only filling every 12th (`0,12,24,...`) item, but in the end take the mean over the entire array. You probably want to create your array as:

```
janNES = np.empty_like(conprecip[0:720:12,6:-11,95:141])
```

And then loop over it with e.g.:

```
for ii,i in enumerate(range(0,720,12)):
    janNES[ii]=(NESprecip[i,6:-11,95:141])
```

`ii` now runs from `0,1,2,..,59` while `i` runs from `0,12,24,..,708`.

---

By the way, you don't need the `for` loops for this, Numpy can select the data directly by slicing the original array:

```
janNES = NESprecip[0:720:12, 6:-11, 95:141]
febNES = NESprecip[1:720:12, 6:-11, 95:141]
```

And you can even calculate the mean directly from this:

```
mjanNES = NESprecip[0:720:12, 6:-11, 95:141].mean(axis=0)
```